# Sort by string and ignore number for display in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need to sort alphabetic data in a table view and ignore numbers, like :

```
- 123 test
- 939 urne
- 403 vase
```

Currently, data is loaded like this:

```
- 939 urne
- 123 test
- 403 vase
```

What's the best choice for ignoring numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store data separately in dictionaries, like,

```
Array
(
   {  
      "number" = 403
      "text"   = "vase"
   },
   {  
      "number" = 403
      "text"   = "vase"
   }
)
```

then you can sort using,

```
NSSortDescriptor * descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"text" ascending:YES];
[array sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

The best Way to this

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor; = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"text" ascending:YES comparator:^(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2) {

            return [obj1 compare:obj2 :NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        }];

    [arrDocuments sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Now start a loop which has all the objects in the array that you wish to sort.  Suppose the name of the array is `originalArray`.

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i = 0; i < originalArray.count; i++)
{
    NSString *tempstr = [originalArray objectAtIndex:i]; // suppose it is 123 - abcd

    NSString *newString = [[tempstr componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];  
    [dict setValue:@(i) forKey:@"num"];
    [dict setValue:newString forKey:@"char"];

    [newArray addObject:dict];

}
```

Now you can sort `newArray`:-

```
NSSortDescriptor * descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"char" ascending:YES];
[newArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];
```

Now you can get the indexes from the dictionaries present in this array(under key **num**)

```
for(int j = 0; j<newArray.count ; j++)
{
    NSDictionary *dict1 = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    dict1 = [newArray objectAtIndex: j];
    int number = [[dict1 objectForKey:@"num"] intValue];
    NSString *str = [originalArray objectAtIndex:number];

//Now add this string in the finalArray. 

    [finalArray addObject:str];
}
```

I hope you were able to understand this. :)